# accessing php from remote server using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am currently using phonegap to make an apps. As we know, phonegap only allow html css and js to be used. therefore, php cannot be used. I have researched a bit and I found out that I can just put the php file in a remote servers and used the ajax to call for the php file using the url of the remote server. however, it still cannot call the php file.

here is my ajax snippet of code in the login.html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var dataString = 'name1=' + username + '&password1='+ password;
        var theUrl =  'auth.php';
        if(username==''||password==''){
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: theUrl,
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    if (result == "right") {
                        window.location.href = 'home.html';
                    } else {
                        alert("Wrong username or password");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

As I am testing using auth.php which is still in the same folder as my login.html, everything works fine. but when I use the url of the file in the remote server, it always fails.

Thanks in advance for responding.

Comment: can't use a relative url to access a remote server

Comment: @charlietfl, is an absolute url something like this format protocol://another.domain.name/dir/filename? so in my case is it http ://example.com/auth.php? thanks.

Comment: yes , include full url and make sure you white list it in phonegap and CORS enable the output

Comment: @charlietfl I tried already, but once i click my button, it did not give me anything. I am suspecting that it still tried to contact my server and it will fail because of too long. is this server problem or what? thanks.

Comment: is it white listed and CORS enabled?

Comment: @charlietfl I am still trying using my xampp, I have not tried in the phonegap yet.

Comment: inspect request in browser dev tools console

Comment: @charlietfl after inspecting the javascript, it gives me this output: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/auth.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: that's why I asked if it is CORS enabled. Google the error

Comment: @charlietfl although I have added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") in the auth.php file, it still gives me the same error. I have tried using login.html inside my local folder to contact with the auth.php inside my localhost, so it can be said as cross domain. It works when I add the header in the auth.php, but when I remove it, it does not work. I wonder why my file in the server still have that problem.

Comment: header isn't always enough. keep reading about CORS. Lots of posts here regarding same issue

Comment: nevermind. I tried again and it finally works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1.**Using localhost**

try this url

`theUrl=http://10.0.2.2/yourfilepath` but  this will work only in  emulator **not in browser**.If you want test browser disable the web security first and then try it.

2.**Using liveserver**

Access the files like a website url access 
eg:`www.apptest.in/test/auth.php`

Comment: my html is actually in the localhost, but my php is in a free server i have used.

Comment: are trying to access a php file that located in a liveserver or localhost?

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") in the php file and it works like a charm. Thanks anyway for asking :)